# Which all values in build.prop indicate that device is using custom ROM/is rooted?

Tags: android

I'm using a custom ROM in my device. While it passes the SafetyNet test banking apps detect root/rom. I tried changing the device fingerprint but the app is still detecting rom. Which all values should I change?

Edit: Device is Moto G5 Plus, ROM is ArrowOS 9, rooted using Magisk

Comment: Why you think that it checks the build.prop?

Comment: Someone said that it checks build.prop. Because otherwise my root/ROM is well hidden (other apps don't detect it)

Comment: I have just realized that your question does not relate to software development, and is off-topic here.